# Can I make Visual Studio's "go to definition" option always show the metadata instead of source code?

Tags: visual-studio

I've been searching for this for an hour or so, but can't seem to find an answer to my question.

I've always found the "view metadata" on "go to definition" extremely useful, while the decompiled / source view is usually not what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to force Visual Studio to show the metadata every time. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback to ask for features.

Comment: I can do that, but wanted to check I'm not missing anything before I do.